# Can you place elements other than classes in a class diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I'm currently doing up class diagrams for a project I'm working on.   I feel there's something that should be represented in my class diagram but I'm not quite sure.

I have a *.csv* file which the whole system essentially works on, which is created by a java class on a once off basis (i.e it will never be done again). Is this something I should represent on my class diagram and if yes, how should I go about doing it?

Comment: You can do anything you want.  That said, it is called a *class* diagram.

Comment: There are 14 different diagrams in UML, surely you can find one that is more suited.

Comment: You can place every element in your class diagram which your diagramming tool allows. However, you should also think about the purpose **why** for **for whom** you are drawing these kind of diagrams. Will your audience understand anything which is not "standard UML"? Do they need that information in graphical form, will that help them for their work? Are you just creating conceptual class diagrams - which leaves you some degrees of freedom - or do you generate code from them, which means your diagrams must follow some strict rules?